# Sums of divisors of perfect square having certain number in 1's place

Tags: number-theory

Let $M^2$ be an odd perfect square,are there any numbers which cannot be in the one's place for $\sigma (M^2)$ ?

For instance $\sigma(5^2)=31$, which has a 1 in the one's place and $\sigma (7^2)=57 $,which has a 7 in the one's place, and $\sigma (11^2)= 133$, which has a 3 in the one's place. What about $5$ and $9$? I am sure that this is likely but also curious if anyone knows of any results related to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe $\sigma(11^{2n}) = 1 +11 +...11^{2n} \equiv 2n +1 mod(10)$ which generates $1,3,5,7,9$

Comment: http://oeis.org/A065764/b065764.txt is worth a look. It indicates that the ones digit of $\sigma(n^2)$ (even allowing even values for $n$) is rarely $5$.